# Why doesmy android app work fine on my device, but not on others, where my components are misplaced?

Tags: android-layout

I have created my first android app.

It works fine on my device, all components are at the right place and same size, but when I run that on another mobile phone, all components are misplaced!

What's the problem? It's specially with ImageView.

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:src="@drawable/backg"/>

   <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">   

       <ImageView
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:id="@+id/chart"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

       <Button
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Next"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:onClick="clickedOnPlay2"
        android:background="#4cb076"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

  </RelativeLayout>
   <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

[MyPhone_Screenshot](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6Xb0FQuKgJDQkRObDBKUTdJak0)
[OtherPhone_Screenshot](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6Xb0FQuKgJDRGhqTTVPendJTm8)

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: not working bro,same problem...is i have to create different layout directory like layout-small,layout-large???have you checked my screenshots??

Answer (score 0):

**Try this layout file :**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/backg"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.user25.myapplication.MainActivity">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="320dp"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            android:id="@+id/chart"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Next"
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:onClick="clickedOnPlay2"
            android:background="#4cb076"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
            />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>


</LinearLayout>
```